# Java- Sort String with multiple decimal points

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, comparator

I have a `Hashmap<String,Integer>` and the key is a unique string which is in the below format:

```
"abc1.0","bcd1.1","xyz2.1.1","cdef1.2.1"...
```

now I need to sort this hashmap with that key but in the numeric order with decimals in the below order:

```
"abc1.0","bcd1.1","cdef1.2.1","xyz2.1.1",...
```

I was trying the Comparator with A treemap but did not sort it properly.

ex:

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
        .....
        //Counted decimal points and if > 2
        k1 = Integer.parseInt(key1.substring(1).split("\\.")[countOfDecimals]);
         //same for key2 
         ......
      } 
      return Double.compare(k1, k2);
}
```

**EDIT:**

- maximum number if decimals points are '4'
- Should be sorted by the Numeric value, please ignore the text

Almost tried all the examples given is STO but nothing worked out :(
It does not sort if two or more decimal points are involved. Please Help !!

Comment: I don't think they're decimal points if there are multiple...

Comment: Your example is confusing because it's not clear whether you're sorting alphabetically or only by the numeric suffix.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of "decimals" or to the values between them?

Comment: Why are you using `Map<String, Integer>` while these stings are obviously not integers (eg `1.2.3.4` is not an integer, it's a string that consist of four integers). A map stores unique keys, and ignores duplicates, so you cannot map the same key - say `xyz2.1.1.4` to many integers (2,1,1,4). Could you explain this, because it is unclear to me what you want to achieve using this MAP ? Why don't use a simple List or Array and just sort it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using regex to extract all the decimal numbers and sort them:

```
Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return Double.compare(Double.valueOf(a.replaceAll("[^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?]","")), 
                    Double.valueOf(b.replaceAll("[^\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?]","")));
        }
    });
    mp.put("abd10.9",6);
    mp.put("abd17.02",65);
    mp.put("nmbd1.02",17);
    mp.put("klbd7.028",10);
    mp.put("klbd7.023",9);
```

//ascending order

> {nmbd1.020=17, klbd7.023=9, klbd7.028=10, abd10.9=6, abd17.02=65}

//The changes as discussed in the comment below:
//this can only work when the decimals are of the same length, if not then zeros should be added to fill up the remaining space for the sorting to work well

```
 Map<String, Integer> mp = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String a, String b) {
            return Integer.compare(Integer.valueOf(a.replaceAll("\\D+","")),
                    Integer.valueOf(b.replaceAll("\\D+","")));
        }
    });
    mp.put("abd10.9.0.9",6);
    mp.put("gbd17.0.6.2",65);
    mp.put("nmbd2.0.9.2",17);
    mp.put("klbd7.0.2.7",10);
    mp.put("rlbd8.1.2.8",10);
    mp.put("opbd9.0.2.3",9);
    mp.put("mpbd7.0.3.2",9);
    mp.put("wpbd7.0.7.0",9);
```

output:

> {nmbd2.0.9.2=17, klbd7.0.2.7=10, mpbd7.0.3.2=9, wpbd7.0.7.0=9, rlbd8.1.2.8=10, opbd9.0.2.3=9, abd10.9.0.9=6, gbd17.0.6.2=65}

Comment: This relies on numbers being single-digit.

Comment: @shmosel it extracts numbers before and after the "." and in this case it is not restricted the length of the decimal numbers so it catches everything, like this also,"[^\\d+\\.\\d+]" a simple concept to catch decimals

Comment: But your sort would put 10.0 before 1.10.

Comment: 10.0 is *not* smaller than 1.10.

Comment: @shmosel yes that is the ordering, by swapping a and b, greater numbers against smaller and vice verse. it depends on the a and b, how do you want it to be? 10.0 >> 9.8 >> ... 1.09.

Comment: @shmosel i updated my answer, the sorting order can be changed by swapping a and b.

Comment: @SeekAddo, I tried your solution. but it works only for 2 decimal ponts.. if I use something like "abc1.2.3", then it will throw a "NumberFormatException". please help !

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva what is the length of your decimal, you can extend the regex to more decimals

Comment: @NomeshDeSilva oh ok, then you cant make a double out of it, you can use Integer and use regEx to get the numbers as Int, but dont forget that all the numbers muss be of the same length otherwise sorting will not be correct, example 1.0.2.1 and 1.2.3 will not work unless 1.0.2.1 , 1.2.3.0, just by putting zero to the remaining space to get all the numbers in the same length, 1021 compareTo 1230, this will work for you when you use Integer.compare and change the regEx to "\\D+"

Comment: @SeekAddo thanks. but can you please update your answer in that order?

Comment: @SeekAddo thanks for your time brother.. it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try extracting the numbers out from the string in the keys and have the tree sort on them. When you end up having a list like "1.0", "1.1", "2.1.1", "1.2.1" ...

and you sort on them it would return your expecting order:

"1.0", "1.1", "1.2.1", "2.1.1"

Comment: This relies on numbers being single-digit.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to tokenize the String - split it into:

- text
- version (**1**.2.3)
- subversion (1.**2**.3)
- subsubversion (1.2.**3**)

And then compare the text using string comparator, and iterate overs all versions/subversions and compare them using integer comparison.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is extract the number portion of the strings in the keys you are comparing:

For example, if the keys are "abc1.5.02" and "zxy1.4.3", then the number portions are "1.5.02" and "1.4.3"

Next, pad the components of these number strings so that they have 2 digits in each subversion.

That is,

```
"1.5.02" --> "1.50.02.00.00" (add "00"s since you can have up to 4 decimal points)
"1.4.3"  --> "1.40.30.00.00"
```

Next, convert both of these to a long.

```
"1.50.02.00.00" --> 150,020,000 (call this val1)
"1.40.30.00.00" --> 140,300,000 (call this val2)
```

Finally, return `Long.compare(val1, val2)`